# how can i set a value for X amount of cells in a worksheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i am reading the automate the boring stuff with python and wanted to modify one of the code used in the book. im trying to set a font for a range of cells and give those cells a value. but i keep getting a error

This is the code that i am trying:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.styles import Font 

wb = xl.Workbook()
sheet = wb["Sheet"]

italic24Font = Font(size=18, italic = True) # creating a font type, this returns a font object

for rowNum in range(1,100):
  cell = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1)
  sheet[cell].font = italic24Font
  sheet[cell] = "what is happing?"

wb.save("idk.xlsx")
```

Error that i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\JO\Desktop\Automate the boaring stuff\Chapter_13_Excel\projects\other\testing.py", line 12, in <module>
 sheet[cell].font = italic24Font
  File "C:\Users\JO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 290, in __getitem__    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
  File "C:\Users\JO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 133, in range_boundaries    
m = ABSOLUTE_RE.match(range_string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: A guess: `cell.font = italic24Font`.

Comment: ^Same for the next line too.

Comment: @BigBen tried it, and it did not work. i dont get any errors but i just get a empty spreed sheet!

Comment: also to add, when i put a print statement at the end of the for loop to print the cells values i get the value it has. but when i open up the workbook it does not have text in the cells.

Comment: `cell.value = `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not accessing the cell correctly. You could access the first cell with `sheet["A1"]`, but since you already have a reference to the cell, just change the font directly on the cell rather than via the sheet. You can also set the cell's value with `sheet.cell()`.

```py
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.styles import Font 

wb = xl.Workbook()
sheet = wb["Sheet"]

italic24Font = Font(size=18, italic = True) # creating a font type, this returns a font object

for rowNum in range(1,100):
  cell = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1, value="what is happing?")
  cell.font = italic24Font
  
wb.save("idk.xlsx")
```